# Control floating point precision of compile time computations in VS2010 C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, floating-point-precision

It seems that the VS2010 compiler is computing expressions with double precision unless the compiler optimization is completely disabled (`/Od`).

```
static const float a = 1.0f;
if (b < (float)(1.0f + a))...
```

Here, `1.0f + a` is first computed with double precision and afterwards casted to single precision if optimization level is other than `/Od`. Unfortunately, when setting the compiler floating point model to `strict`, we cannot use precompiler `#defines` with computation expressions, therefore this is not an option.

How to deal with that in an appropriate way and force the compiler to compute the above statement with single precision?

Comment: How are you determining the precision being used?

Comment: The origin is that we saw differences between Debug and Release build and it was tracked down to the described precision issue. We don't know a way to "see" the compiler in action.

Comment: This [article](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/03/22/intermediate-floating-point-precision/) seems relevant, perhaps `_controlfp_s(&oldState, _PC_24, _MCW_PC);`?

Comment: For 32-bit x86 applications, older versions of VS default to using x87 FPU which the CRT defaults to setting to "round-to-nearest, double-precision, no exceptions". With more recent versions of the compiler, you can use /arch:SSE or /arch:SSE2 and it will generate code using SSE instead which has explicit single vs. double instructions. The same is true by default of x64 native. In these cases, the legacy precision control setting is irrelevant.

Comment: BTW, why do you care about it being double instead of single?

Comment: I care because the results shall be compared to the same code compiled for and running on a different CPU architecture. The goal is to reach bit equality.